# Initializing GLFW using a DLL throws an error

Tags: c++, opengl, dll, glfw

I wanted to put the code initializing GLFW (and a window) into a dll, but there seems to be something I'm doing wrong.

```
    GLFWwindow* window;
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
if (!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    std::cout << "Window Initialization failed";
    return nullptr;
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
return window;
```

I have put the above code in a method called 'test' in the same .cpp file as my main method, which works fine. However, when I move the code to a DLL and then invoke (the exact same) method it returns nullptr, outputting "Windows Initi .. failed".

```
GLFWwindow* window = test(800, 600);
GLFWwindow* window = gldll::Initialization::initializeGLFW(800, 600);
```

'test' works fine, the method from my gldll::Initialization class doesn't work.

I suspect this problem lies in the way I link my dll with my project, but other methods from the same dll work fine.

EDIT:
I now added glfwInit(); to the method above. In my main method, when I set my context to the window the method returns and I try drawing to it it only shows a white screen.

Comment: As I recall GLFW uses Thread Local Storage for context management and that can get tricky when a DLL is involved. That said, the more pressing issue is that I don't see a single call to `glfwInit (...)`.

Comment: Don't worry, I call glfwInit in another method. I also see that simply putting the method in another class within the same project results in the same error. Is there any known way around thread local storage?

Comment: No, the TLS is used in order to keep track of which context is currently active in the calling thread (`_glfwPlatformGetCurrentContext (void)` for example, invokes `TlsGetValue(_glfw.win32_tls.context)`). As long as you initialize your DLL in the correct order (which likely means calling `glfwInit (...)` from within the DLL) it should not be an issue.

Comment: Alright. I call glfwInit() from inside the DLL now, and then (in my main method) call glfwMakeContextCurrent(GLFWwindow* window) with the return value of my DLL method as input. I now get a white screen no matter what. Any ideas?

Comment: I think your DLL has to encapsulate all GLFW-related stuff if you do it this way. You'd have to create a DLL function that wraps `glfwMakeContextCurrent (...)`. You can see an explanation of this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).